# Creating own LiveWallpaperPreview?

Tags: android

I would like to create my own LiveWallpaperPreview, i.e. to show the user a fullscreen preview of what the selected Live Wallpaper looks like (without the "Set Wallpaper" and "Settings" button that the stock-OS preview has).

Rebuilding the LivePicker-Class from 2.1 ([android.git.kernel.org](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/wallpapers/LivePicker.git;a=tree;f=src/com/android/wallpaper/livepicker;h=1557e0ae77aa8b0f8191472a204b5a7b4add31a4;hb=master)) works great, so I am able to let the user select a wallpaper to be previewed, but the actual LiveWallpaperPreview-Class tries to import the following private Interfaces/Classes:

`import android.service.wallpaper.IWallpaperConnection;

import android.service.wallpaper.IWallpaperService;

import android.service.wallpaper.IWallpaperEngine;

import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperSettingsActivity;`

Is there any way to display a LiveWallpaper in my app without resorting to using the private APIs (which I obviously don't want to do)?

Thanks!

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this. The live wallpaper picker is part of the Android operating system and cannot be replaced.

Comment: Hi Romain,

thanks for your answer. I don't want to _replace_ the picker, merely _use_ it for my own app: I just want to display a Live Wallpaper to my app's user. Is that not possible either? 

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: I just figured out that you can use Theme.Wallpaper as your activity's theme to display the LW that is currently in use - far more simple than I would have thought :-)! However, Is it possible to display other wallpapers that the user has installed (that are different from the currently selected one) with this method?

Comment: Sorry there isn't a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the same problem, but also hit a dead end.

My idea was that I didn't need access to IWallpaperConnection etc., but that I could use reflection on the bound service.

However, I get 
WARN/ActivityManager(96): Permission Denial: Accessing service ComponentInfo{com.android.wallpaper/com.android.wallpaper.grass.GrassWallpaper} from pid=4196, uid=10070 requires android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER

The permission android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER is required for viewing the wallpaper and it is a system permission not available to normal apps.

EDIT: 
Created an app called Current Wallpaper that is available on the market
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.elsewhat.android.currentwallpaper

It basically displays the current wallpaper in a standalone app and allows you to change the wallpaper through an intent to the standard wallpaper picker.

The app uses the theme android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"