# How do I launch the Preview/Select Wallpaper activity for my Wallpaper from inside an Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, preview, wallpaper

I think my question is fairly straight forward... how do I launch the standard activity for previewing my Live Wallpaper from within an Activity (of the same application)?

*Edit: In Logcat... here is the entry when you launch the intent I want to use...

04-06 09:44:08.369: INFO/ActivityManager(17452): Starting: Intent { cmp=com.android.wallpaper.livepicker/.LiveWallpaperPreview (has extras) } from pid 21944

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

1. Make an activity that holds the Live Wallpaper fullscreen
2. Open that activity using:

   Intent i = new Intent(this, [Activityname]);
   startActivity(i);

Comment: Not really... there is a default Activity in android for previewing a Live Wallpaper. I want to make use of that Activity/Intent to use the generic Live Wallpaper preview activity on the device. I assume you need to pass the intent (whatever it is called) some extra information about the live wallpaper you want to preview.

Comment: More like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749791/creating-own-livewallpaperpreview ?

Answer (score 0):

Hahaha.. This answer is coming a little late. ;-)  But, I don't think it's been answered correctly yet so here goes... What I gather is that you want to launch the wallpaper chooser.  There's two ways to do that depending on which android version, you'll see below.  You can only specify YOUR wallpaper after version 16. Otherwise, you launch the chooser and the user specifies the wallpaper.

```
   if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.service.wallpaper.CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER");
        intent.putExtra("android.service.wallpaper.extra.LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT", new ComponentName(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(getApplicationContext().getPackageName()))).append(".LiveWallpaper").toString()));


        try
        {
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return;
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException activitynotfoundexception)
        {
            activitynotfoundexception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }
    Intent intent1 = new Intent();
    intent1.setAction("android.service.wallpaper.LIVE_WALLPAPER_CHOOSER");
    try
    {
        startActivity(intent1);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException activitynotfoundexception1)
    {
        activitynotfoundexception1.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Live Wallpapers not supported", 1).show();
    }
    finish();
```