# Launch wallpaper from activity

Tags: android, android-activity, live-wallpaper

I coded a live wallpaper for Android. The wallpaper works fine, the only issue is that users complain sometimes because after install they cannot find the wallpaper icon in the application menu.

I found several solution to this issue. The most satisfactory seems to be [this one](http://www.yougli.net/android/live-wallpaper-binding-an-activity-to-the-open-button-of-the-market/).

The tutorial above suggest to create a `main` activity that triggers the wallpaper chooser. This solution is quite good. However, I would prefer to launch the preview of my own live wallpaper from my activtity, not the wallpaper chooser.

I found some suggestion in the comments of the page above and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547769/how-do-i-launch-the-preview-select-wallpaper-activity-for-my-wallpaper-from-insi).

but I didn't manage to make them work.

Any idea on how to do this?
Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the solution here: [Start a live wallpaper service from activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081258/start-a-live-wallpaper-service-from-activity)

This does what I wanted to do, but it works only for version above 4.1, so if anyone has additional solution that work for versions below 4.1, please let me know..

Comment: There is none below Version 4.1, common practice is to tell the user he has to select your wallpaper with a Dialog or Toast, before the Wallpaper Chooser is started.